# Include file content into property?

Tags: php

I've a file called `helper.php`, in this file I've a list of functions (without class).

Now I need to include the content of helper file, into a property. For do this I've create a loader, this is an example:

```
class Loader
{
    function include($helpName)
    { 
         return include $helpName;
    }
}
```

this Loader is used by my class like so:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
         $this->load = new Loader();
         $this->email = $this->load->include('helper.php');
         $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

unfortunately I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function validate_email() on integer

if I print: `var_dump($this->email);` I'll get: `int(1)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this seems to me a strange way of contructing a helper. Why not making a helper class??

Comment: @Jeff I understood what do you mean, an helper class that return the instantiate file?

Comment: no, a helper class that has the methods/functions you need.

Comment: @Jeff is a way, but I'm looking for a simple inclusion of functions into a property, even if is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're specifically returning at the end of your class, it doesn't work that way. From the docs:

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

I'd look into [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) classes, or you can also create a class, and return that from your `include.php`.

```
public class Email
{
    public function send()
    {
        echo 'Sending Email';
    }
}

return new Email();
```

An example with autoloading:

```
//Create Email.php
public class Email
{
    public function send()
    {
        echo 'Sending Email';
    }
}

//Main file, set a register, so when it doesn't find a class, it will load from a file, and auto register it.
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});


class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
         $this->load = new Loader();
         //If Email class doesn't exist, it will load it from 'Email.php', and then initialize it.
         $this->email = new Email();
         $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have a file with just a bunch of functions, including the file anywhere will simply put them into the global scope. If you want them confined (To a variable, let's say), you'd want to work with a class.

Answer (score 0):

Included code always runs in global scope. If you want your functions to be incorporated as methods of a class then you would need to create a new file wrapping the functions in

```
 <?php
 Class somename {
  ?>
```

And...

```
 <?php
 }
```

But writing self modifying code is inherently dangerous. And its ugly. And it will be sensitive to whether you explicitly end the included file with ?>

An alternative approach which **sucks as much** as that above, is to get a list of the defined functions, and invoke these from the _call() magic method:

```
 Class somename {
   public $included;
   function _call($fn, $args)
   {
     return call_user_func_array($this->included[$fn]), $args);
   }
 }
 $obj=new somename();
 $before=get_defined_functions();
 include('helper.php');
 $obj->included=array_diff(get_defined_functions(), $before);
```

But you wil find that your included code will not run outside of a class if it references $this

Short version: do not do this